# How to apply theme to report builder tablix?

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I created a report in report builder, how do I apply theme to my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it best to use the wizard and select a theme when using that. Applying a theme after is difficult as it has to be done manually.